# How can I convert multiple Flash CS6 files to Flash CS5?

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs5

I know that I can convert a single .fla from CS6 to CS5.5 or CS5 using File > Save As...; however, I have many files I need to convert. Is there an efficient way to perform this task repeatedly?

Comment: Having a peek at the [JSFL Docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/extend/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9024f3f-7fa0.html) it doesn't look like it's possible because of the save dialog. Maybe you can make a [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/) script ?

Comment: First time I hear about Sikuli, usually I would of resorted to AutoIt v3 (scripts are written in Visual Basics pretty much), but screenshot-based scripting looks awesome with Sikuli! :)

Answer (score 5):

Use Flannel.

http://ajarproductions.com/blog/2012/03/06/flannel-open-newer-fla-files/